# Should tags primarily be used for categorization or searchability?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently wrote a question about C interop in Swift: [Converting a C `char` array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string). The tags, originally, were [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) and [tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuples). I chose these because before asking, I searched for something like "c array to swift string".

Another user came along and insisted that it did not belong with the C tag, because the question was only marginally about C, and could apply to people using C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ as well.

This is correct: the question has really little to do with C itself. I'm even asking for a "pure Swift" solution. In my opinion, though, the main purpose of tags is to facilitate search, and since "C array" unambiguously designates the construct in question (regardless of how many other languages share it), it is inevitable that anyone with this problem will eventually look for "C array".

It appears that in his opinion, the main purpose of tags is to neatly categorize questions. I can see why: people can follow tags, and followers of the C tag could be disappointed if all they got were questions about interop to a different language.

At the same time, tags are meant to overlap and most C-tagged questions actually deal with a library that only happens to be written in C.

Similarly, people having C interop problems would probably look for questions tagged C and whatever language, and I think that searchability is more important than standalone categorization. I think that it's justified to use the C tag to talk about interop between C features and another language.

Said user went ahead and retagged the question, changing [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) to [interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interop), which I find less searchable. Should I roll it back?

Comment: google search result appears accordingly wth tag...

Answer (score 20):

As you said already, the problem with the "search-ability" strategy is that it clutters the tag that is less relevant for the question and decreases search-ability in that tag.

If a question is tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) it will show up if a user looks for [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) questions. Which doesn't make much sense because the question is not about C.

Sure, it's somehow related. But enough to justify a tag? Not really.

Since you are active in that area you should be familiar with [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), a tag that became pretty much useless because almost everything that is related to iPhone development can and will be tagged with Xcode.
Does Xcode thrown an Exception at you? Good luck finding relevant information because most of the results you get by searching "[xcode] YourException" are about iOS apps that throw exceptions.

So yeah, (correct) categorization is the way to go. I categorize for the people that answer my question.

Is an expert in C and no knowledge in Swift able to answer the question? No
Is an expert in Swift with no knowledge in C able? Maybe
Is an expert in Swift with knowledge in Objective-C able to answer? Probably

And only one of these follows the c tag.

Comment: My view is that tags are relevant for answerers only until the question has an answer, but stay relevant to people looking for help for an indeterminate period. As for [tag:xcode], it's unfortunate for people with "true Xcode questions", but if it means that inexperienced people can search for "xcode" instead of "iphone", it's probably not just a loss either.

Comment: @zneak: As I said, the problem is that what you really asked was about swift native/platform interoperability, not any relation to C the language itself. And while you might maybe make a case for array (a tag I think is nearly useless anyway), there is none for C. Substituting any of those other languages I listed would be equally good (or rather bad). BTW: Good work on the meta-question.

Answer (score 7):

One of the tags that I follow is [imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imap) and in my experience most questions tagged with it are either about Google's extensions to IMAP, or about specific third-party libraries on which you can build an IMAP client or server. Neither type of question is typically about IMAP. The former already has its own tag and doesn't need the IMAP tag unless the eventual answer is one provided by IMAP. The latter should, in my opinion, be tagged for the library only, unless it is actually a question about IMAP (for example, about the order of issuing commands), something the asker might only know once it is answered.

And that is for me how one should tag: do not overuse tags where they are only of marginal concern, and retag as answers come in.

Your question's name and body should be searchable, but the tags should be about the mechanism that provides your solution. That way the tags make them findable by people that have the same problem, but that might come from a different background than your question.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting conflict. Both policies you present seem plausible to me. My inner-nerd likes *correct categorization* better though. If people use incorrect terms (see other answers here), then our hope should be that thanks to proper tag usage they will learn better. Or (assuming the tag is not incorrect), they will learn to abstract irrelevant details from their problem and will find the general answer.

Also, my guess is that the official stance on this is [as presented on the tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags):

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

So it seems like the preference is given to the answerers if it comes to tags. But of course it is possible that this particular formulation was not intentional in the context you present.

Answer (score 3):

It's neither "[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array)", nor "[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array)", it's "[null-terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/null-terminated) [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)" or "[c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string)" (by the way, possible synonym?). That is, it has nothing to do with C, both searchability-wise and categorization-wise. Null-terminated strings [weren't event first used in C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Compare Google results:

- [Google: "c char array"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22c+char+array%22) — 39,400 results
- [Google: "null terminated string"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22null+terminated+string%22) — 219,000 results
- (Can't include "c string", it shares the name with thongs...)

You should just use the correct term.

Comment: C arrays translate to Swift tuples, which cannot decay, while C pointers translate to a generic Swift pointer wrapper. For this reason, the semantic difference between a `char*` and a `char[N]` is relevant, and "null-terminated string" says nothing about it. Whether the character array is null-terminated or not has little relevance to the problem, since the main issue was emulating decay in Swift.

Comment: "c string -thongs"?

Comment: @zneak The accepted answer expects a null-terminated sequence of UTF-8 characters. If anything, [tag:null-terminated] is a relevant tag. What you're describing is already covered by the [tag:array] tag.

Comment: @Braiam Unfortunately, Google doesn't provide even remotely reliable stats for complex queries. There're more results for `"c string" -thong` than for `"c string"`...

Comment: @Athari, "null-terminated sequence" is strictly less precise than "character array". This issue does not exist when you have a char pointer on the C side rather than a char array, and yet a null-terminated sequence is agnostic to that. Why should I settle for a less precise term when there's a perfectly appropriate one? Martin R used a constructor that accepts a null-terminated UTF-8 character sequence, but there are also constructors that accept a char pointer and a length. That's simply not the crux of the issue.

Comment: In other words, the question was about the construct, not the contents. If your problem was to get a pointer to a C int array as a Swift UnsafePointer<Int32>, you'd use the same approach.