# Should an old question be edited to use a newer programming language (Objective-C replaced by Swift)?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

The [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) programming language was
introduced by Apple on the occasion of the WWDC in June 2014. Since then,
the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag has become quite active (> 24.000 questions as of now).

Out of curiosity, I searched for the first question about Swift and
found this:

- [tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552725/viewforheaderinsection-default-standard-value)

A question from **October 2009**, which predates the introduction of
Swift by more than 4 years!

As it turned out, the question was edited in January 2015. In particular,
the existing Objective-C code was *replaced* by the corresponding
Swift code, and the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag was added. The editor then
posted an answer (using Swift).

(There are about 30 questions with the Swift tag which were originally
posted *before* that language became known to the public. For most of
them, the Swift tag and a Swift answer was added later. This is 
probably OK, because many question are about the *frameworks* and not
about the *lanugage*, as was discussed in [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the Objective-C tag and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-in-swift-on-ios-os-x-questions-marked-with-the).)

Is it okay to edit an old question and *replace* Objective-C code with Swift code if I am going to post an answer using Swift?

Comment: Nope, and I'm *pretty* sure this has been asked before.

Comment: Wow, talk about...not even close to appropriate.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

No.

Who are you to say that the old question is out of date?

There still plenty of people working with older technologies in this and other areas.

By all means add an answer using Swift (or what ever the new technology is) but clearly mark that you know that the question was asked some time ago.

Besides, editing the question like that will undoubtedly invalidate any answers the question might have received.

I've rolled back the question to its original state. I suggest that next time you come across something like this you do the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought (but this was my chance to post the first meta question :) What about adding the [swift] tag? Is that OK (in your opinion) even if the question was about Objective-C?

Comment: @MartinR - Why add the tag? The question isn't about Swift, it's about Objective-C.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-in-swift-on-ios-os-x-questions-marked-with-the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280173/should-tags-primarily-be-used-for-categorization-or-searchability?s=7|0.2848

Comment: "I know in this case there's little chance that someone is still writing Objective-C" - That's probably incorrect. While Swift is the hot new thing, there is and will be tons of code using Objective-C. It will be a while before Swift eclipses Objective-C in practice, and even then we'll need to use and maintain those Objective-C codebases. Rewriting older Objective-C questions into Swift is just plain wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: @BradLarson - Ah. Sorry. I thought the iOS ecosystem was rather fast moving in that regard.

Comment: @ChrisF Swift is technically at v1.1 release and v1.2 beta right now, but it's still seen as something to use concurrently with Obj-C and to start new projects with. A lot of people aren't confident enough in its adoption (for whatever reason) to spend a lot of time converting everything to Swift, so a lot of apps have either taken the transformation slowly or not started at all, because Obj-C is still very much supported, and from what Apple is saying, it sounds like it will continue to be for a while.

Comment: @AstroCB Count me as one of those not confident enough to adopt Swift. I've looked at it several times since it was announced, and I believe it's the "wave of the future" (shudder), but I don't actually care for the language, and (IMHO), it's still a language in alpha. Not only will I not convert any old code yet, after 4 months of really frustrating development, I convinced a newbie developer to convert an entire app **from** Swift **to** Objective-C, at which point, everything worked much better and more smoothly.

Answer (score 21):

Quoting [the most-upvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285266) (by Robert Harvey♦) on the weaker question
[Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the Objective-C tag and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258):

> If the question is tagged [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), you should do your best to answer it in Objective-C. It's the same throughout the website; Java questions typically don't get answered in Scala.

Re-tagging to make the question the one you want to have is worse than simply mis-answering.

Select comments:

> answers in any other language than the one tagged should get your answer down-voted at best and flagged not an answer or both at worst. –  Jarrod Roberson Feb 4 at 16:47

> Answering on Objective-C it's the way to do it, but contributing on helping the iOS ecosystem moving forward to a new way of doing things as it's Swift should be Ok too. –  axierjhtjz Feb 4 at 16:57
>
> > @axierjhtjz Not sure I agree. Moving the iOS ecosystem to 'a new way of doing things' is Apple's agenda, and it's not our responsibility to further it. If the ecosystem does move, it should happen organically because it's what iOS developers want to happen. And in that case the questions will naturally trend towards asking for Swift more than Objective-C, without any deliberate action on the community's part. –  aroth Feb 5 at 0:49

Answer (score 17):

The only acceptable edit introducing a newer technology is one adding a link to a separate-but-similar question involving the same task and new technology.

The new question should definitely link the old one.  But in some cases, such as Objective-C vs Swift, where the new technology is supposed to be the successor, then it's ok to edit the old one to say it involves the dated approach and for the new glamorous way, see this other question.

That way both are preserved.  It certainly is not ok to destroy the old question.