# Should we change the tag excerpts for Swift and Objective-C?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

As there accrue more and more answers to iOS/OS X related questions in either the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) language, I for one would like to distuinguish between questions in either language. And, for me knowing only Swift, it feels kind of natural to add the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) or [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag to a question in that language.

If so, should one redefine the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) and [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tags (or excerpt of the tags), to also allow for questions/answers written in that language? And not only answers related to the specifics of the given language?

EDIT: Original excerpt tag (with link to tag info):

> **[tag Objective-c](//stackoverflow.com/tags/objective-c/info)**: This tag should be used only on questions that are about Objective-C features or depend on code in the language. The tags "cocoa" and "cocoa-touch" should be used to ask about Apple's frameworks or classes. Use the related tags [ios] and [osx] for issues specific to those platforms.
>
> **[tag Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info)**: Note : Use this tag only for questions that are specific on Swift language features. Use the related tags [ios] and [osx] for issues specific to those platforms.

Swift is a programming language designed by Apple for creating iOS and OS X apps. Swift retains some elements from C and Objective-C, but offers many modern features such as generics, closures, optionals, tuples, type inference, and operator overloading.

And is it correct/polite/... to re-tag older question written in Objective-C with the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c)-tag? New questions seem to already differentiate from older questions with the addition of the Swift tag.

---

P.S. I have seen the [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions marked with the Objective-C tag and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/), and feel that is a different discussion, although related. I feel the general trend is to answer a question in the same language most of the time, although the alternate language solution could provide guidelines.

P.P.S. I have also seen the [Should an old question be edited to use a newer programming language (Objective-C replaced by Swift)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287600/), and do agree on keeping the old question in the original language.

Comment: Don't hesitate to improve tagging. Just try to make the edit substantial, and don't go too much on a retag-only crusade, some people are allergic to that. Especially as you don't have the editing-privilige yet.

Comment: I see your point regarding creating a edit-review-queue, but is it approved of to improve tagging? And should we(/someone) redefine the tags?

Comment: I think those language-tags should be used like all the others. If one wants code in the answer, one better tag with the right language, not only with the tag. Though if the language really doesn't matter, tagging only the framework might be more appropriate and lead to a better result.

Comment: I don't understand your proposal. The ObjC tag is already very clear about only applying to questions that _require_ use of that language. Are you suggesting that the guidance be changed to indicate that Swift answers to ObjC questions are acceptable?

Comment: I do not want to accept language changes. I read the tags as if they indicates that the question should **only** be about *language features*, and not a specification that this question is in that language. The proposal is to clarify allowance for question and answers in the given language, primarily.

Comment: Tricky. "Objective-C" used to mean in practice "iOS or MacOS X". In ten years, "Swift" will mean in practice "iOS or MacOS X". Right now there are lots of people who learned Objective-C but can read and write Swift, but also some who are Swift-only.