# Is it OK to edit an answer to mark the question it is posted under as a duplicate target for another question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Getting Output Volume on Mac in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471622/getting-output-volume-on-mac-in-swift)*

So I asked on how to GET the system volume level in Swift. I did a lot of searching (including searching for answers on Stack Overflow) and could not find the answer. So I posted a question.

Then someone else marks my question as a possible duplicate. The question which I supposedly had duplicated was showing how to SET system volume in Swift, not what I was looking for. But then this question which I supposed duplicated is updated to included an answer on how to GET system volume and my question is changed from a possible duplicate to an actual duplicate.

So my question is this: Shouldn't a question only be marked as a duplicate if the duplicated question is answered in the original answer of the question it supposedly duplicated? In other words, to update the answer to a question just to mark another as a duplicate just seems downright wrong, doesn't it? Seems like it would have been just better to answer my question directly. Also, the person who asked the question that I supposedly duplicated was asking how to SET system volume which was totally not my question anyway.

My complaint is that people on Stack Overflow seem so eager to pull the duplicate card than to read the question and help the user out. Why can't we be a little more flexible here and allow a similar question instead of always quick to mark it as a duplicate?

In short, here is what I am trying to say: Another question on Stack Overflow was updated so that my question could then be marked as a duplicate. Is that right?

Comment: Hmm... I'm too naive to look at the questions side-by-side and see why one isn't a dupe of the other.  Are you suggesting then that the person who marked your question as a dupe is trying to shoehorn your question into another answer?  (That's a faux-pas.)  Did you make any edits to your question to differentiate the two questions?

Comment: Your question isn't even closed. Obviously the efforts you've already put in to prove it wasn't a duplicate have been effective.

Comment: @KevinB:  There's a spat with the close voter who's trying to close the question as a dupe.  It seems like there's more to this than the duckspeak standard responses we'd normally give would indicate.  *Something* is strange here, and sure, the OP could do more to edit their question to differentiate, but let's not dismiss this out of hand just yet.

Comment: Those supposed duplicates aren't duplicates. I am asking about updating a question to mark another as a duplicate.

Comment: Can we get a Swift expert in here??  Geez.

Comment: My issue is that the question was updated and then mine marked as a duplicated after I asked.

Comment: meh. what's the big deal? you got your answer, right?

Comment: @KG7UAT You should not be accusing people of not reading your question and not being willing to help you out, when they have provided you with a solution that does in fact solve your problem, and that you found helpful.  That you're more concerned with your reputation than getting a solution to your problem is...not a good sign.  Be glad that people took the time to help you solve your problem, and don't make false accusations about them.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, and I lost all my reputation because of it

Comment: Are you sure that's why your question received downvotes?

Comment: @Servy I'm not accusing, that's what happened. I am a bit concerned about my reputation because I'm afraid I could lose the ability to ask questions again.

Comment: @KG7UAT No, it's not what happened.   People clearly *did* read your question, and provided you with a solution that solves your problem for you.  Stating that they weren't interested in providing a helpful and *when they gave you a solution that was helpful to you* is just objectively false.  That you're at risk of losing the ability to ask questions doesn't change the fact that you were in fact given a helpful answer by the people you falsely claimed didn't.

Comment: So, here's how i see it. You asked, "How do i get the output volume for MacOS in swift? This is how i did it for iOS, can anyone help?" That's a perfectly valid on topic question, however, questions of that nature receive downvotes all the time. You can't reasonably prove in any way shape or form that the downvotes were due to people thinking it was a duplicate. It's more likely that the downvotes were the result of the tone of responses in the comments.

Comment: Looking at the edit history and your reputation history, the first downvote didn't come until long after your post had been closed as a dupe and then reopened. (2 hours.)

Comment: Man, I wish I could just be understood. I am failing to communicate what I am trying to say. @Servy Those people did not answer my question. It eventually came to the point where someone else's question was updated so mine could be marked as a duplicate. The updated answer worked, but I am a little disappointed in how my question was answered.

Comment: Relevant: [Why do Swift questions on Stack Overflow get marked as duplicates of ObjC questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289230)

Comment: _"eager to pull the duplicate card than to read the question and help the user out"_ If you get a solution to your problem, you've been helped. Can you articulate the harm that the duplicate closure actually causes you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm sorry I am not getting my point across, communication is not my strong point. What my complaint is that an answer to another question was updated so that my question could then be marked as a duplicate. It just seems like people are so eager to mark a question as a duplicate.

Comment: I got that, but I don't understand why you think that's wrong.

Comment: Of course we're eager to mark as a duplicate; that helps you, and anybody else who runs into that issue in the future, and we don't need to write yet another answer that says the same thing on a new question.  That's...sort of the whole point of duplication in the first place.

Comment: One thing worth nothing is that duplication isn't a punishment.  Yes, it does prevent additional answers, but it's there to help future readers find a better answer.  If anything, duplication gets you an answer *faster*, because someone else already had the same issue, you couldn't find it, but now you know where to look.  That's a good thing, isn't it?

Comment: @fbueckert Yes, but it seems like that goes too far sometimes. Mine wasn't a duplicate, but it was made a duplicate. And what's wrong with having similar questions? Sometimes one size doesn't fit all.

Comment: Because we want questions to help as many people as possible.  Your question triggered an update, so that future readers are helped even more, you got your answer, everybody's happy!  Aren't they? I don't see how that's a bad thing.

Comment: _"what's wrong with having similar questions"_ Nothing, and that's why we just point duplicates at each other and (generally) don't delete them. It's a funneling mechanism.

Comment: I don't know I am so confused right now. I feel like it was someone's way of saying you did not do your research.

Comment: It's not; it's a way of saying: "your answer is already ready for you, right here: [link]".

Comment: I certainly understand why editing an answer to accommodate your question _feels_ wrong. It's like being tricked: you did your research, there was no duplicate, you ask your question expecting an answer, and suddenly there's a duplicate anyway. The downvotes don't help either. I think striving to condense knowledge in one answer is a noble goal, but I understand how this feels wrong to you. I just hope you don't take this as a discouragement and continue asking good questions.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That's exactly what I was trying to say. Thank you! I will try not to be discouraged about it.

Answer (score 16):

I believe it's all right.

The experts reading your question believed that the difference between 'get' and 'set' operations didn't need yet another Q&A.

Since you disagreed that the duplicate target fully answered your question, they added the additional details to the other answer to make it a better target. You agreed that those details made it a better target, and that the edited answer helped you resolve your issue.

Doing that they both helped you to solve your problem, they improved an existing post so it would help future visitors, and they avoided posting extremely similar posts in different places.

This outcome better serves everybody.

Remember that having your question closed as a duplicate is not bad in itself. Users were just pointing you (and future visitors) to the answer you needed.

Just be happy that you got what you needed, and move on. The objective was not to get an answer posted *under your question*, but to get a solution to your problem.

Comment: @KG7UAT *Good* duplicate questions enrich the site, because it makes it easier for a visitor to find the right answers. Their search terms may fit your question better, and then they are guided to the answers.

Comment: I *happily upvote* good duplicate questions, and hope others do the same. What I look for specifically are keywords not used in the target *and* a clear, specific question.