# Tags C and C++ .... should it really only depend on the posted source?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is somehow related to [Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags), but not quite the same. I just came across a question that was initially tagged with both tags. The code shown was clearly C++. But the root of the problem with the code lied in the usage of a <strike>C API</strike> *C standard library function*. So, to my understanding, the Q&A was helpful to both C and C++ programmers. Someone edited the question, removing the C tag. Personally, I think this is harmful in that special case. In fact, being totally strict it was a C question, but paraphrasing the shown code to C would have been a *major* edit.

So, what do you think -- should the code shown really be the only determinant for which tags are appropriate? I feel like it should depend on whether the question and answer is applicable to the language tagged.

Edited for clarification: Just using *any* API that happens to be implemented in C indeed doesn't justify a C tag, as one answer points out -- I agree with that.

Edit #2: This duplicate accusement is **ridiculous** and a bad example of some behaviour on here. I'm not talking about a question showing "only C code" but tagged C++, I'm talking about a question showing clearly C++ code but the root of the problem was a C standard library call!

Comment: Some SO users suffer from a pretty serious case of parochialism and will insist there can be no crosstalk between languages.  Even if it is a very common practical usage case.   I post answers to a C++ language extension tag, one of the posters here spent weeks of his free time to remove the [c++] tag from them.  Pretty hard to stop them, they are willing to invest an enormous amount of energy to avoid learning anything new.  Just roll back the edit, the odds that it will last are however not good.

Comment: Downvoted because you did zero research into previous discussion of this topic on meta

Comment: After seeing what is happening on here, I really don't want the poster of this particular question being exposed to **this**.

Comment: Hmmmmmm what is happening here? Discussion? Well, yes...that's the point to ask something on meta, I think. My POV is: rename [tag:C] with [tag:Pascal]. Now repeat your question _"Tags Pascal and C++ … should it really only depend on the posted source?"_. They share something, true, but they're different languages. Like C and C++

Comment: I'm referring to those who don't want to discuss but prefer to "do away with it" my marking it as a duplicate of something different.

Comment: Most of the time, if the problem stems from a C standard library function call in a C++ program, the problem is precisely that the code is using a C function instead of a C++ function or technique, and very often the fix is to use the C++ native library or facilities instead of the C function.  The techniques that are appropriate if the program is C++ are usually not applicable if the code is C, and very often the converse applies too, but including both tags makes it unclear which is really wanted.  Please don't encourage dual tagging; it makes it hard to provide good answers.

Comment: For those arguing against double-tagging, I wonder how they would handle the case of a question asked with a [c++] tag that has a duplicate existing question with a [c] tag (or vice versa). Would you still vote to close even though they are "different languages" ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter maybe. Maybe also editing new/old question to use the _right_ tag (C **or** C++). Of course ready for exceptions, blind closing votes/retagging is seldom useful.

Comment: Related: [Should tags primarily be used for categorization or searchability?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280173/should-tags-primarily-be-used-for-categorization-or-searchability)

Comment: remotely at best. Tagging the question because its problem and solution applies to C clearly follows the *categorization* approach. People here seem just *in general* opposed to it, only because the example code happens to show C++ around the problem.

Answer (score 20):

Tags are used to indicate the relevance of a question to specific programming topics, tools, libraries, etc.

If both C and C++ are relevant to a single question, then I see no problem with tagging that question with both of the languages. The relevance can be just from code, or it can be from APIs that can be used from either C or C++, or really any other reference that is applicable to both C and C++.

Comment: If the code is C++, it should not be tagged C.  If the code is C, it should seldom be tagged C++.  They are two vastly different languages, and there are very few questions that should be dual-tagged.  90 times out of a 100, dual-tagging is wrong.  That leaves a fair margin for 'some questions benefit from dual tagging'; I think I've probably left too big a margin and the claim should be for more than 90% being incorrectly dual-tagged.

Comment: What I don't understand is how often both C and C++ tags are relevant to same question. Yes, of course, there are **corner cases** where it applies however they're exceptions (and IMO OP should explain this in his question, no one will complain if he says _"I'm tagging both C and C++ because..."_).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They're not *vastly different* (in that C is a ~80-90% subset of C++), still I agree with your rough numbers. I see a **lot** of dual-tagged questions just because the op has no clue about the differences. The motivation for my post here is that it seems there's an automatic reflex (probably because of those many inappropriate tags) for some users to remove one of the tags *no matter what*

Comment: A big -1 from me. It is very rare that a question should be tagged with both. Please do not encourage it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen is C a subset of C++? Can I kindly disagree? If you think so then you're right about double tagging. _Unfortunately_ they're **two different languages**.

Comment: It is due to the fact C++ was designed to be a superset. It's not complete, but as I wrote you WILL find 80-90% of C in C++. This doesn't make them somehow the "same language" as many confused people may believe, so your emphasizing is not really contradicting me. (And I have to add, as much as e.g. Microsofts crap annoyed me before until i found a way to compile C (**not** C++) code in VS ... claiming they had nothing in common like any other languages is just not hitting it)

Comment: Felix: just be clear. With *super-set* you imply that C++ has all features C has (or, as you say, 80/90% of them). However it's not. C++ is _compatible_ with C standard library and it has a very _similar_ syntax but languages are different (I hope I don't have to repeat here that (in)famous list). In fact they're different languages (yes, that's true!). Some rare times they interop (=you use C library in a C++ program) but  if you use printf() in C++ then you're not writing C code. Any doubt about this?

Comment: With this in mind then...how often you need to tag, let's say, a question with both [tag:c++-cli] and [tag:C#]? It's not impossible but rare enough to be an exception unless, for example, you're explicitly issue a problem with them (let's say to consume indexed properties made in C++/CLI  in C#).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Where do you get 80-90% from? Here's one way to look at it. The C++ standard has 30 clauses. 15 of them (Member access control, Special member functions, Overloading, Templates, Exception handling, the Strings/Localization/Containers/Iterators/Algorithms/Numerics/IO/Regex/Atomics/Thread libraries) are about language features or library elements that do not at all exist in C. And those cover *very significant* features of C++...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti is it so hard to understand? a (near) superset **doesn't** make it **the same language**, that's not what I'm saying. And the case with C# and C++ (be it CLI or not) is a different one, C# was never designed to be a superset of C++ (thanks god btw...) ... and Barry, you got the interpretation of the percentage figures wrong. It means 80-90% of valid C code is also valid C++ code. A 100% superset would mean ALL C code would have to be valid C++ code, still C++ could have 3 times the features...

Comment: Felix. Why on Earth you think if you write printf() in C++ then you're writing C code? You're not. if you write if (a > 2) then are you writing C code? No, you're not. Given that why you would ever tag a question with both tags? C++ is not a C compiler with 80% of C standard library and tons of new features, catch this. This has been widely discussed on meta and main site. If they're different languages then it makes **no sense** (99.999%) to use both tags and this has been widely accepted.

Comment: Yes you may propose to change this and even create a new unified tag [tag:c-or-c++] but I doubt you'll get any support from people who knows C or C++ just a little bit. One question with both tags is a corner case (and yes people shouldn't blindly remove one of them when they see a question) but you'll see it once every 1000 questions. That said this is my opinion, meta is the place to discuss about this and get consensus.

Comment: Case in point, someone following the policy you advocate: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31658868/1

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti are you misunderstanding **on purpose**? your examples are silly (sorry) and I just stand my position that the tag should indicate the *relevance*. That would still make double-tagging wrong in almost all cases, but not in all. I'm waiting for really good counter-arguments (standing the point that only the code shown should decide). But instead, some funny guys declare it a duplicate of a *related* post (but **not** quite the same).

Comment: Silly? Absolutely yes! That's why they were so _extreme_. Think that it's what (many) people think when they see a question with C and C++ tags together. What's your question? _Should we tag according to source code?_ No, we shouldn't because it doesn't matter if you use printf() instead of cout: if you're compiling with a C++ compiler then you're still writing C++ code. _There may be cases where a question can be double tagged?_ Of course yes but they're so rare that we may consider them exceptions, _rule_ (reasons?) are described in _supposed_ dupe of this question.

Comment: You may argue that sometimes (or even _often_) the same question can be valid both in C and in C++. In that case it's probably a bad question (or answer). It's extremely rare to write C++ code that it's also C code (it means you're not using C++ features at all and, for example with void* casts, you will have bad C code). It's also rare to write C code that is _decent_ C++ code (because probably you're not using C++ features). In most of that cases (I think) this _compatibility_ should be in answer, not in question (unless OP is aware of it and it's what he is looking for). ù

Comment: I would like to see a link to such question (good question plus good answer that can be tagged both C and C++) for each upvote on this answer...

Answer (score 10):

No, it is absolutely not a good idea for questions about standard library functions to be tagged both C and C++. C++ does not import the complete C standard library unmodified, it adjusts some of the functions so that they work better for C++. Most people answering know how a function works in C, or know how a function works in C++, but not both, and guess about how to use it in the other language. That guess is usually correct, or at least close enough, but not always. Additionally, even if a function works the same way in both languages, best practices on how to use it, and even on whether to use it at all, can still be different. Good answers for a C question are often bad answers for a C++ question, and vice versa. Using the tag for the language that the OP is actually interested in means getting better answers.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, but the fact that you are using a library which *might* be written in C from your C++ code does not a C question make.

Why do I say "might"?
Because there are *many* languages which allow using that calling convention, and we don't want to introduce [c-the-language-and-this-time-i-really-mean-it-damnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-the-language-and-this-time-i-really-mean-it-damnit).

You might make a case for using [cdecl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdecl) if the calling convention matters, but that's the extent of it.

---

If you really want to ask the C crowd, consider asking an equivalent C question instead. Shouldn't be hard, as you asserted that everything important is the same in C anyway.

Comment: The case I was talking about was using a function of the *C standard library* ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: So? It's also part of the C++ standard library. And there's no guarantee it's written in C.

Comment: That's the whole point of this discussion: Is it useful to C programmers? I think yes, it is. What's your argument it is not?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: My answer is definitely no, too much noise drowning out the C questions if everything remotely related is tagged C.

Comment: That's in my opinion not *remotely* related but *directly* and for *too much noise*, have a look at the `c#` tag. But I see your opinion seems to be somehow representative on here...

Comment: [While I think you are right and it's representative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280180), feedback to date *on this question* is too sparse to show it.

Comment: The answer you linked makes perfect sense to me, still I think it's a bit different when the source of a problem is the usage of a function of the *C standard library*, which I consider being part of the *language C*.

Comment: And that's what I'd like to put up on discussion here. It might be a corner case, but the *problem* was clearly C, although the shown code was C++. In my opinion, it shouldn't even be tagged C++, but then you had to rewrite all the shown code.

Comment: Remove the other-language part and make it C or pseudo-code, and we can talk. Because then, you know, you no longer have a some-other-language-than-C question.

Comment: I would automatically be less annoyed when SO users follow [the edit guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267607/17034) they recommend.

Comment: @HansPassant: A good part had all the editing needed done, but proper tagging. Most of the rest only had minor issues left, which I fixed. There are also a few which would need a full rewrite from scratch, with new/the missing data from the OP, but I cannot get that. Might I have edited a few of them too little? Certainly possible. (I went back through the last 8 posts I edited just now.)

Answer (score 1):

The question you should ask yourself is:

#### Do someone that only knows C (or C++) have the qualifications to answer the question?

If the answer is "no", obviously the tag shouldn't be used. The same reason why sometimes some people wonders "why the heck I'm seeing this question!". Here lies where the propose of the tags shines, either you know the answer to the question (also, evaluating the correctness of the previous answer) or you are interested to acquire that knowledge.

The only reason why I would use more than a language tag is when is more than obvious that the question require more than one area of expertise to be accurately answered, otherwise seldom to do so.

Comment: I don't agree with `have the qualifications to **answer**`.  Tags are mostly based on who might want to later find this question, not who will answer this question right now.  While they're usually overlapping sets, I don't think focusing on who will answer is a right approach.

Comment: @Joe ["A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. **Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able *to answer*** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) That's the first definition of tag, and main propose. Others that are listed or you think of are secondary.

Answer (score 1):

This is now live: [Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)

It addresses this specific issue:

> A question should be tagged with both c and c++ if it is about:
>   ...
>
> - C++ code that uses C libraries (for example code using extern "C").

This means cases like C++ code using C libraries like pthreads.h, Windows API, Linux API and so on.

Questions about the C standard library, or how to use that one from C++, is another story. I think it will have to be handled on case-by-case basis.